# Room Dao error: SQL error or missing database (no such table)

Tags: android, android-room, dao

I have a requirement for two different `Room` tables with the same `ShoppingListItem Entity`. So, I recreated another `Entity` data class model with the same properties but with a different name, `CustomSortShoppingListItemEntity`. But, Room throws the error stating that there is no such table which is specified as `custom_sort_shopping_list_items` in the `CustomSortShoppingListItemEntity` data class. Do I have to create a separate `Dao` for the `custom_sort_shopping_list_items` table? How can I fix this?

**Error message**

```
error: There is a problem with the query: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such table: custom_sort_shopping_list_items)

public abstract java.lang.Object countCustomSortListItems(long listId, @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
```

**ShoppingListItemEntity**

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "shopping_list_items",
    foreignKeys = [ForeignKey(
        entity = ShoppingListEntity::class,
        parentColumns = arrayOf("id"),
        childColumns = arrayOf("shopping_list_id"),
        onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
        onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
    )]
)
data class ShoppingListItemEntity(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Long = 0L,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "shopping_list_id")
    var shoppingListId: Long = 0L,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    val name: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "category")
    val category: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "quantity")
    val quantity: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "set_quantity")
    val setQuantity: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "set_total")
    val setTotal: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "unit")
    val unit: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "item_ppu")
    val itemPPU: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "item_set_ppu")
    val itemSetPPU: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "notes")
    val notes: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "coupon_amount")
    val couponAmount: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "set_coupon_amount")
    val setCouponAmount: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "item_total")
    val itemTotal: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "item_set_total")
    val itemSetTotal: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "image_uri")
    val itemImageUri: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "thumbnail_uri")
    val itemThumbnailUri: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "is_in_cart")
    val isInCart: Boolean
)
```

**CustomSortShoppingListItemEntity**

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "custom_sort_shopping_list_items",
    foreignKeys = [ForeignKey(
        entity = ShoppingListEntity::class,
        parentColumns = arrayOf("id"),
        childColumns = arrayOf("shopping_list_id"),
        onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
        onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
    )]
)
data class CustomSortShoppingListItemEntity(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Long = 0L,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "shopping_list_id")
    var shoppingListId: Long = 0L,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    val name: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "category")
    val category: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "quantity")
    val quantity: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "set_quantity")
    val setQuantity: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "set_total")
    val setTotal: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "unit")
    val unit: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "item_ppu")
    val itemPPU: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "item_set_ppu")
    val itemSetPPU: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "notes")
    val notes: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "coupon_amount")
    val couponAmount: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "set_coupon_amount")
    val setCouponAmount: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "item_total")
    val itemTotal: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "item_set_total")
    val itemSetTotal: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "image_uri")
    val itemImageUri: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "thumbnail_uri")
    val itemThumbnailUri: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "is_in_cart")
    val isInCart: Boolean
)
```

**Shopping List Items Dao**

```
@Dao
interface ShoppingListItemDao {
    //===== SHOPPING LIST TABLE =====//

    //Create
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertShoppingListItem(item: ShoppingListItemEntity)

    //Read
    @Query("SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM shopping_list_items WHERE shopping_list_id = :listId)")
    suspend fun countListItems(listId: Long): Int

    @Query("SELECT * FROM shopping_list_items WHERE shopping_list_id = :listId")
    fun getAllShoppingListItems(listId: Long): PagingSource<Int, ShoppingListItemEntity>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM shopping_list_items WHERE id = :id")
    suspend fun getShoppingListItemById(id: Long): ShoppingListItemEntity

    //Update
    @Update(entity = ShoppingListItemEntity::class)
    suspend fun updateShoppingListItem(item: ShoppingListItemEntity)

    //Delete
    @Delete
    suspend fun deleteShoppingListItem(item: ShoppingListItemEntity)

    //===== CUSTOM SORT TABLE =====//

    //Create
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertCustomSortShoppingListItem(item: CustomSortShoppingListItemEntity)

    //Read --> Throws error here
    @Query("SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM custom_sort_shopping_list_items WHERE shopping_list_id = :listId)")
    suspend fun countCustomSortListItems(listId: Long): Int

    @Query("SELECT * FROM custom_sort_shopping_list_items WHERE shopping_list_id = :listId")
    fun getAllCustomSortShoppingListItems(listId: Long): PagingSource<Int, CustomSortShoppingListItemEntity>

    //Update
    @Update(entity = ShoppingListItemEntity::class)
    suspend fun updateCustomSortShoppingListItem(item: CustomSortShoppingListItemEntity)

    //Delete
    @Delete
    suspend fun deleteCustomSortShoppingListItem(item: CustomSortShoppingListItemEntity)

    //Update All
    @Query("DELETE FROM custom_sort_shopping_list_items WHERE shopping_list_id = :listId")
    suspend fun deleteAllCustomSortShoppingListItems(listId: Long)

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertAllCustomSortShoppingListItems(customItems: List<CustomSortShoppingListItemEntity>)
}
```

Comment: What about using inheritance instead of defining the same entity for 2 different classes?

Comment: I found the source of the error: I forgot to include the `Entity` data class in the `Database` abstract class definition.

Comment: @Kozmotronik But, `CustomSortShoppingListItemEntity` has the same exact properties as `ShoppingListItemEntity`. So, how can inheritance work in this case?

Comment: The inheritance was a workaround for the problem, not meant to be inheriting purposes. If this _I found the source of the error: I forgot to include the Entity data class in the Database abstract class definition_ resolves your problem then no need for workaround. Is your problem resolved anyway?